# Looping with condition javascript dont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

i'm trying to make some looping with condition inside of it using javascript, this example code

```
for (var i in GexfJS.graph.edgeList) { 
            var _e = GexfJS.graph.edgeList[i]
            if ( _e.source == _nodeIndex ) {
                var _n = GexfJS.graph.nodeList[_e.target];
                _str += '<li><div class="smallpill" style="background: ' + _n.color.base +'"></div><a href="#" onmouseover="GexfJS.params.activeNode = ' + _e.target + '" onclick="displayNode(' + _e.target + ', true); return false;">' + _n.label + '</a>' + ( GexfJS.params.showEdgeWeight && _e.weight ? ' [' + _e.weight + ']' : '') + '</li>';

            }
        }
```

and it show only nodes that connect with _nodeIndex, but i want to show another nodes that related from connected nodes that connect with _nodeIndex , and the code like this

```
 for (var i in GexfJS.graph.edgeList) { 
        var _e = GexfJS.graph.edgeList[i]
        if ( _e.source == _nodeIndex ) {
            var _n = GexfJS.graph.nodeList[_e.target];
            _str += '<li><div class="smallpill" style="background: ' + _n.color.base +'"></div><a href="#" onmouseover="GexfJS.params.activeNode = ' + _e.target + '" onclick="displayNode(' + _e.target + ', true); return false;">' + _n.label + '</a>' + ( GexfJS.params.showEdgeWeight && _e.weight ? ' [' + _e.weight + ']' : '') + '</li>';
            _nodeIndex = GexfJS.graph.nodeList[_e.target];
            var _curr = _nodeIndex;
                    for (var j in GexfJS.graph.edgeList) { 
                        var _ed = GexfJS.graph.edgeList[j]
                        if ( _ed.source == _curr ) {
                            var _no = GexfJS.graph.nodeList[_ed.target];
                            _str += '<li><div class="smallpill" style="background: ' + _no.color.base +'"></div><a href="#" onmouseover="GexfJS.params.activeNode = ' + _ed.target + '" onclick="displayNode(' + _ed.target + ', true); return false;">' + _no.label + '</a>' + ( GexfJS.params.showEdgeWeight && _ed.weight ? ' [' + _ed.weight + ']' : '') + '</li>';

                        }
                    }
        }
    }
```

but the code above is not work properly, it show nodes which only connect that related to the _nodeIndex.
my question is, which alghoritm that im wrong if i want to show the nodes which related connected from the nodes that related from the _nodeIndex,
example :

A related to B , C

B related to D , F

C related to G , K

F related to M , N

M related to Y , Z

so if i click node A it will be related to B and C ,
but the goal is if i click node A it will be related to B, C, D, F, G and K

thanks

Comment: Did you actually intend to put one iteration inside the other, with the same variables? Try using unique variables, and try logging the variables to see what you've got.

Comment: yes i've been trying to using unique variables, but still  dont work